# Get Windows 10 to install in an OSX VM

Tags: macos, windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I have a macbook pro with El Capitan and VMWare Fusion. I want to install a legal copy of Windows 10 (the cheapest available) that would work for sure in a VM.

So what is that minimal/safe version compatible with VM installations? and where I can get it? I am trying to look into Microsoft's page but it is extremely confusing.

I expect to get a downloadable version, so I don't have to wait for the DVD to arrive.

Comment: Windows 10 is Windows 10...lots of places offer both physical and digital licenses of Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

> So what is that minimal/safe version compatible with VM installations?

In general, any version of Windows 10 will work in a VM as well as any other.

> where I can get it?

[Microsoft's online store](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Windows-10-Home/productID.319937100), or practically any retail computer store.